# Python smtplib connection reset by peer

Tags: python, urllib, smtplib

I'm using SMTP lib to send emails with Python, and am suddenly encountering errors connecting to the mail server. I have never run into errors before and have sent many emails using this code - the only possibility I can think of is that I've recently updated to Mac OS 12.3.1 and that this may have modified my python installation in some way. Has anyone encountered (and resolved) a similar error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subtest4.py", line 25, in <module>
    userIP = urlopen('http://ip.42.pl/raw').read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1345, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```